# ASP.NET MVC 5 assigning input value with javascript cause DbEntityValidationException

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

UPDATED : The idea is simple : I want to populate an input field with a default value for ImageTitle field of my model. The value come from the database. This default value should be the Filename (also stored in db). The user has the option to leave it as it is or change it before the page is POSTed.

I have a view that renders a form with html helpers like `@EditorFor`. Once the page is loaded (`$(document).ready()`) I tried to use JQuery to set the value of an editable `input` with the id `label-title` but it turned out that when I was posting the page I got an exception. This exception is not present if I enter manually an imagetitle in the input.

I tried to assign ImageTitle a value in the GET edit action method. `myImage.ImageTitle = myImage.Filename`

Like it did with JQuery, the input is populated properly with a the value but when I POST the page, same exception occurs.
`An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'UseType'. Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' in EntityFramework.dll Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Web.Mvc.dll`  This exception seems to be unrelated to my real problem, since I don't get it if I remove the single line `myImage.ImageTitle = myImage.Filename` and the app function perfectly.

Here is some code that I use.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ImageTitle, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "label-title", @class = "form-control" } })
```

generates this html

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line valid" id="label-title" name="ImageTitle" value="benq160715074510.jpg" type="text"></input>
```

I don't get any error when I enter manually a value for ImageTitle but everything I've tried with either JQuery, Javascript or assigning a value in controller action trigger an exception.

My edit method is pretty standard

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "All my fields here including ImageTitle..")] TutoringImage tutoringImage)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Db.Entry(Image).State = EntityState.Modified;
            Db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(Image);
    }
```

Can anyone help on that one?

Comment: Why are you using javascript? Just set the value of `ImageTitle` in the GET method before you send the model to the view (i.e the same as `@ViewBag.currentFileName` and delete the `ViewBag`). And your creating invalid html.

Comment: I agree with @StephenMuecke. You do not need Javascript to accomplish this.  You are making it more difficult for yourself

Comment: That is a good idea, just tried it, it seems to trigger the same exception. Why delete the viewbag ?

Comment: @AlainPaquette can you catch the exception (try..catch block) and tell us what is causing this exception?

Comment: Also by doing it in the GET method the assignment will be done each time someone wants to edit an image and might overwrite a custom title that was set for this image.

Comment: If the user is going to the Edit page, all of the information that should be showing is what the user entered in when they initially created that object.  Sorry, I am confused with what *exactly* you are looking for

Comment: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'UseType'.

Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Web.Mvc.dll

Comment: Can you update your question to include what you have currently?

Comment: I am just trying to set a default value for a field based on another field value, as a starting point. But if the user enter another imagetitle than the filename, I don't want to overwrite it in the future.

Comment: sounds like you just need an `if` statement.. if field value == something.. then set default value for other field.. in the `GET` method

Comment: The error means you have a dropdownlist in your view and `SelectList` your using in it is `null`. Show the relevant code!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not use the attr function in this code `$('#label-title').attr('value', imgTitle);`.

The correct way to fill up a input value is with the value function. `$('#label-title').val(imgTitle);`

Comment: Tried it before but when I looked at the html output I saw value="". Only with .attr I see in my html value field populated with the right value and not staying empty. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @AlainPaquette, This is correct (and your code is generating invalid html by adding `$('#label-title').text(imgTitle);`). But from the comments in your question, you have far more issues that just this.

Comment: Yes, I know this is not valid html but I am playing with what I can to see if the behavior changes. I'll remove that and rerun my tests just to see if this changes something.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked in the end.

My form called an action method called Save() in which I was creating a new TutoringImage object. When I assigned the value on this first occurence of the object, it worked. When redirected to `Edit(int? id)` action, I could leave the field ImageTitle as is or change it without any bug, entry was saved correctly in the db.

What I was trying before that was to populate this field after its creation, first with javascript on the client and the in my controller in the `Edit(int? id)` GET action like this :

```
        if (tutoringImage.ImageTitle == null)
        {
            var query = from db in Db.TutoringImage
                        where db.ImageID == tutoringImage.ImageID
                        select db;
            foreach (TutoringImage image in query)
            {
                image.ImageTitle = tutoringImage.Filename;
            }
        }
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Db.Entry(tutoringImage).State = EntityState.Modified;
                Db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

This failed poorly and I can't explain why. What worked was to assign the "default" value that I wanted on object creation and not after... Simply added a line of code in my object creation in the action method that followed the drag and drop form.

```
TutoringImage im = new TutoringImage
                {
                    Filename = fileName,
                    // and so on
                    ImageTitle = file.FileName,
                };
```